# Android: Listview in a tab activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have this app that there's a list view within the tab activity. This app is a messaging app. It doesn't really send the message, it just saves it to the database and the database will display the message in list view where you can edit it/delete and/or resend it.

So when the user taps on the send button the message is saved to the SQLite Database and the data on the database will display on list view. I have two tabs, one as the history/sent messages or the list view and the other one is new message or editing page. How do I insert the list view that has the database in tab activity?

I only have a simple code for a list view and I copied the database in the http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html. Well basically i just edited their work because the tutorial has everything I need, editing, deleting and storing, the problem is how the list view of database in a tab activity.

Comment: you are leaving out WAAAAY to many details. We need some context. What does your app do? What code do you have? etc.

Comment: great question (+1)! What does your `ListView` code look like? I could make some suggestions now, but without knowing if you are using views or activities in your tabs, or even simply if you are using a tabwidget, I would prefer to work off of what you already have.

Comment: I agree very good question but agree with the others you haven't given any information.  We're not here to write your app for you but to give direction/help on code YOU'VE already written.

Comment: Just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue . create Activity with a ListView ,set Adapter (CursorAdapter is preferable) add to TabSpec , now addTab .

ApiDemoes will be enough to get more idea .